# Foundry workshop Form creation

Tags: palantir-foundry

Not able to submit the form with new input fields and values using action types and functions in the foundry workshop.

In Foundry workshop can we create the new form with input fields and values and those can displays in a object table in realtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a form to create or update an object in workshop. You'll need (1) the correct Action, which could be made using the [no-code logic in the Ontology Manager app](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/action-types/rules/index.html) or using an [edit function](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/api-ontology-edits/index.html); and (2) a way of triggering the Action in Workshop -- usually this is with the [Button Group widget](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/widgets-button-group/index.html).

If you encounter an error when trying to submit the form, you'll need to troubleshoot that specific error. For example, maybe your user doesn't meet the [submission criteria](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/action-types/submission-criteria/index.html) specified in the Action configuration. There are various reasons why an Action form may fail to submit, but it's not possible to address them all in general terms.

Here are screenshots illustrating this answer:
[image: button group widget], [image: creating an object via a form], [image: new objects appear immediately], [image: what an error looks like], [image: edits appear immediately]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, yes, Foundry Workshop can use actions to update an object table in real time.  Can you please paste any error messages that appear when you are not able to submit the form?  Ideally screenshots from both Workshop and the action's configuration in the Ontology Manager App would greatly help in answering this question, but it's understandable if the organization prohibits sharing Foundry screenshots.